# Explain a piece of Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

i have this code

```
function deleteNode(options) {
            $.ajaxService({
                url: 'http://localhost:1209/Pages/services.aspx/Page_load',
                data: { servicename: 'deletenode', nodename:""},
                LoaderConteiner: "#message",
                onStartService: function () { $(".failed-message,.success-message").hide(); },
                onEndService: function () {},
                onResponse: function (response) {
                    switch (response.result) {
                        case "1":
                            $.pushMessage({ message: 'ok', messageClass: 'success-message', delay: 6000, container: '#changemessage' });
                            break;
                        default:
                            $.pushMessage({ message: 'error', messageClass: 'failed-message', delay: 8000, container: '#changemessage' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

and call this function

```
deleteNode({ target: this });
```

I have explain about this code

whats the Role of "options" and "target: this" ?

Comment: the variable `options` is never referred to. Whose code is this?

Comment: This function doesn't really look like it's deleting a node...

Comment: @LeeTaylor whta's the target: this ?

Comment: `{ target: this }` is a javascript object with an attribute `target` that's set to `this`. But the code you posted doesn't really make sense. It doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Options is the parameter of deleteNode.

By passing a construct like this { target: this } you are passing an object literal as parameter, where
'this' is the object context from where you called the deleteNode function.

Inside deleteNode you can call options.target... in you example.

Regards

Comment: Did you understand it?